# XNA Removing Sprite

Tags: xna, sprite

I've got a texture that is being displayed on the screen when a key is pressed. The check for this is in the update method based on a boolean help_on. Pressing F1 is if help_on is false, display texture and make help_on true. If help_on true then make it false and here should be the removal of a sprite. Can anyone give me a tip for this? I already know that this is possibly not the way to do it but I got no idea how to do it another way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do two things to make this work as you intend:

**First**, you need to store the keyboard state across frames, so you can check when the state *changes*. So: when a key is "up" on one frame, and then "down" on the next, you know that key was "pressed" that frame.

**Second**, to toggle a variable, just set the *new* value of that variable to "[not](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negation)" the *current* value of the variable (set it to its inverse).

See the following code, which could be put in your game class:

```
bool help_on;
KeyboardState lastKeyboardState;

protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
{
    KeyboardState keyboardState = Keyboard.GetState();

    // If the F1 key went down on this frame
    if(keyboardState.IsKeyDown(Keys.F1) && lastKeyboardState.IsKeyUp(Keys.F1))
    {
        help_on = !help_on; // Toggle the help_on variable
    }

    lastKeyboardState = keyboardState;

    base.Update(gameTime);
}

protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
{
    if(help_on)
    {
        // Draw your help screen here
    }

    base.Draw(gameTime);
}
```

Comment: I cannot describe how thankful I am for you answer! Thanks a lot :)

Comment: @user2459750 Also please note the small but important bug-fix edit I made to my example code. Sorry about that :)

Answer (score 0):

Since I do not know about your game architecture, I will provide a very simple approach:
In your **Update** method:

```
kbdState = Keyboard.GetState();
help_on = kbdState.IsKeyDown(Keys.F1);
```

It's always good to cache KeyboardState since you'll usually want to process more keys than just F1.
Then, in your **Draw** method:

```
if (help_on)
    spriteBatch.Draw(...); //all your drawing code
```

Comment: Thank you for your time but this did not quite work. Solved though.